# Wordpress - How to hide posts from parent category but not posts from children category

Tags: wordpress

I have this code :

```
            $argsQuery = array(
                'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'cat' => '-1,-10,-25,-26',
                'posts_per_page'   => 7 
            );
```

I want to exclude posts in parent category (id 7), but I want the posts of the children category still visible.
If I do this :

```
'cat' => '-1,-10,-25,-26,-7',
```

the children category also disappear. I've tried category__not_in but it's not working either. Do you know what could I do ?

Comment: You're trying to get categories, 1, 10, 25 and 26. But you don't want 7?

Comment: Doesn't '-1,-10,-25,-26', need to be an array, or just one id? You're just passing it as a string ....

Comment: I'm excluding 1, 10, 25 and 26. They are children categories of another parent so I don't have an issue with them. 
 '-1,-10,-25,-26' seems to be working as it is (it worked with an array as well, but I just let it as it is now).
I'm also excluding 7, but since it is a parent category, and I want to keep its children visible, I'm having trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code, maybe it will work for you.

```
$included_cat_ids = array(1,10,25,26); 
$exclude_cat_id = 7;
$subcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $exclude_cat_id);
foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
    $included_cat_ids[] = $subcat->cat_ID;
} 
   
$argsQuery = array(
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'cat' => $included_cat_ids,
    'posts_per_page'   => 7 
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I want to exclude 1, 10, 25, 26 as well but that's a detail. The most important thing is that the client I'm working for needs to be able to create new categories in the future and that they'd be included without modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for an easy way out of my problem and added a tag on the posts belonging to the parent category and then excluded this tag.

```
                $argsQuery = array(
                'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'cat' => '-1,-10,-25,-26',
                'tag__not_in' => array(33),
                'posts_per_page'   => 7 
            );
```

Thank you everyone !